# Информация по сайту LeakCheck

Tags: безопасность

я первый раз на этом сайте, поэтому заранее прошу прощения, за что либо, просто нигде не мог найти на свой вопрос, хороший ответ. Просто увидел в интернете что это сайт вопросник, поэтому надеюсь что тут мне помогут) Приметил в интернете такой сайт как LeakCheck. А именно его функционал в защите данных и помощи обезопасить себя от утечки личной информации. Но этот сайт мне показался сам по себе фишинговым, хоть он и кичился большим количеством партнёров и сертификатов безопасности. Наверное просто потому что с ним незнаком. Хотелось бы узнать у людей кто знаком с этим сайтом, стоит ли доверять ему деньги взамен защиты данных? Так как для полной проверки данных нужна подписка. Спасибо большое заранее

Comment: К сожалению, этот вопрос является оффтопиком на сайте. Касательно вопроса: лично я бы не доверял подобным сайтам.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не по теме.

Answer (score 0):

Я являюсь представителем сервиса LeakCheck на территории РФ.

Мы занимаемся сборкой и агрегацией утечек слитых сайтов, после чего пользователь может найти свои данные по почте, логину или номеру телефона. Если данные до сих пор используются, срочно меняйте их и не используйте тот же самый пароль впредь.

Услуги на сайте распространяются по модели Freemium, то есть для использования покупка тарифа необязательна. Сайт не является фишинговым, а также по политике конфиденциальности мы не храним поисковые запросы на сайте.